# How to insert day interval in current date in codeigniter?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I need to add the start date and end date in table. So startdate should be current date and the end date is after 30 days from current date. I have tried to do it in following way but it not insert the record in table.

```
 public function insert_details()
      $data = array(
        'tran_id' => $transaction_id,               
         'start_date' => CURDATE(),
         'end_date' => DATE_ADD(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY)             
       );    
  $this->db->insert('user_payments', $data);
   return $this->db->insert_id();
 }
```

Comment: i don't think you can do that since the active record escapes values.

Answer (score 0):

Because ,

```
DATE_ADD(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY) are MySQL functions,
```

You are treating them like PHP functions.

Pass them as a string to MySQL.

Change To:

```
'end_date' => "DATE_ADD(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY)"
```

Comment: after making above changes it insert this value 0000-00-00 in both fields

Answer (score 0):

you can use `$this->db->set()` method, if you want to MySql function in query

```
public function insert_details()
  $this->db->set('tran_id', $transaction_id);
  $this->db->set('start_date', 'CURDATE()', false);
  $this->db->set('end_date', 'DATE_ADD(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 30 DAY)', false);

  $this->db->insert('user_payments');
   return $this->db->insert_id();
 }
```

Comment: now it shows this error :
 Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '))' at line 1

Comment: `echo $this->db-> last_query();` function after insert function to show query

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-d'). " + 30 days"));
```